# Motion of particle - Mechanics problem

Tags: classical-mechanics

The problem is:

> At time $t=0s$ a particle is moving in a straight line and
>   accelerating uniformly at $2 ms^{-2}$. $5s$ later it stops
>   accelerating, but continues to move at a constant velocity for a
>   further $10s$. At time $t=20s$ the particle has an instantaneous
>   velocity of $-4ms^{-1}$.
>
> Calculate the initial velocity of the particle.

Thanks in advance to everyone for help or hints.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

First note that if the particle is accelerated for $5s$ , and there are not other acceleration, the velocity of the particle remain constant at any successive time, so the velocity at $10s$ is the same that at $20s$.

Now use the equation for a uniformly accelerated motion:
$$
v=v_0+ at
$$
with: $v=-4 $, $a =2$ , $t =5$ and find $v_0$.